# Running pure Ruby app on Apache

Tags: ruby, apache

How can I run a simple ruby app like:

```
puts 'hello'
```

on top of Apache? (e.g. I hit http://mydomain.com/hi and Apache answers with 'hello')

Do I need to install some Apache module? It's impossible to do it without some kind of framework (Rails, Sinatra, etc...)? It's frustrating to think that I need more than a web server to do this...

I'm asking this question just to clarify my understanding of how a Ruby app runs on a web server. I also accept reading suggestions.

Comment: In this possible duplicate he is using Sinatra, not just a single ruby script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Apache module for running Ruby scripts, but the thing is, **nobody uses it**. That isn't how you run web applications in Ruby.

The way it is done in Ruby (and most languages that aren't PHP) is, your Ruby program runs in a separate application server and Apache proxies to it. This means your Ruby script needs to actually handle HTTP requests and emit HTTP responses. Fortunately, there are about 20 million frameworks to handle that work for you.

The simplest example would be with the microframework Sinatra. Using Sinatra, we would write:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :port, 3000

get '/hi' do
  'hello'
end
```

If you saved this in hola.rb, you would start the application server by doing `ruby hola.rb`.

Then you would change your Apache configuration to include something like this:

```
<Location /hi>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
```

Comment: Using this setup you need just to install the Sinatra gem? No apache modules needed?

Comment: @jackantares: Well, the ProxyPass directives require the mod_proxy module to be enabled, but it's normally included with Apache, so you don't need to install anything special. It's probably worth pointing out, though, that [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) is a popular app server you *can* install that integrates into Apache and makes a lot of configuration stuff easy (for example, configuring workers so you can handle more than one request at a time), so you might be interested in that.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand... So the question is handling the HTTP requests and responses. If I build a raw ruby app, I would need to do it by myself.